# Cannot connect to Lotus Notes DIIOP on SSL port 63149

Tags: java, lotus-notes, corba

The company I work for creates software that crawls and indexes various sources for use in search, in this case we're completely stuck on attempting to connect to Lotus Notes over SSL. This is a classic case of "it worked in dev, but failed in prod".

The problem is further compounded by the fact that we're devs and techies, not Lotus Notes experts.

Basically we have a piece of Java software that connects to Lotus to grab the DIIOP IOR text file using this command:

```
String ior = NotesFactory.getIOR(host, userIOR, pwdIOR);
```

Now, this is a non-SSL connection and requires username and password to connect. This works perfectly every time.

Then we attempt to create a session using this:

```
session = NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR(ior, args, this.user, this.pwd);
```

where:

```
args[0] = "-ORBEnableSSLSecurity";
```

When connecting we consistently receive this stack trace:

```
NotesException: Session closed due to communications failure
    at lotus.domino.cso.ORBCallback.make_error(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Generic.make_error(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.corba._IObjectServerStub.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.Session.initSession(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.cso.Session.createSession(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionUP(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionWithIOR(Unknown Source)
[ ... ] 
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset: Connection closed: Host: <redacted> Port: 63149  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 1 completed: Maybe
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.IIOPConnection.purge_calls(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.ReaderThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:154)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Message.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.Message.createFromStream(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.IIOPInputStream.prefill(Unknown Source)
    at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.IIOPConnection.createInputStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I understand the most common reason for this is because we're not correctly importing the TrustedCerts.class file, however after double and triple checking it's in the class path just fine (and the fact it works in dev environment) we're confident that it's being loaded in.

We know if we disable SSL (aka remove the aforementioned arg) our code will connect to the non-SSL DIIOP port 63148 and work just fine however it is a project requirement that all data must be passed through SSL.

Which finally brings me to my actual question: **How do we get Lotus to report why this connection is failing?**

I've tried upping the DIIOP log level to 4 which apparently should show all transmissions but the logs show nothing when I attempt to connect. Also it's worth noting the DIIOP service is definitely running and on the correct ports as well.

I've also checked that we're making it through the firewall to the remote box and TCPDUMP on our RedHat machine clearly shows that we establish a connection with the remote Lotus Notes host before it responds closing the connection.

```
[Pertinent Information]
Application: Java
Library: NCSO.jar
Lotus Version: Domino 8.5.3 FP6 
Lotus Server: Windows Server 2008 Standard 
Ports: 63148 (non-SSL), and 63149 (SSL)
```

Comment: Well, I got one step closer: It would seem the Third Party CA certificate that is used for the TrustedCerts.class file at my client is not giving us a useful TrustedCerts.class file.

We're going to try and set up a self-signed cert to see if anything changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the answer was clear as crystal but not something I was actively looking for.

The reason this doesn't work is that the third party certificate is not a SHA-1 certificate and Lotus Notes 8.5.x only supports SHA-1 ([as per this documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418982)).

So basically that certificate of theirs can never be used for SSL authentication programatically or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned DIIOP logging, but if the connection is failing in the SSL handshake, then the guts of the diiop task probably don't know what's wrong since that's occurring at a lower level in the stack. There are, however, additional debug variables that can be set on the server.

```
DEBUG_SSL_HANDSHAKE=1 
DEBUG_SSL_CIPHERS=1 
DEBUG_SSL_ALL=1
```

The last setting can be pushed up to 2 or 3 for more detailed information.

Restart of the server (or possibly of the server's diiop task) may be required to get the settings to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I've got them set but need to wait before they revert back to a third party certificate and re-issue the TrustedCerts.class file